# Applying for CAN+ Canada visitor visas

Tags: visas, canada

My wife and I both have valid US visas. As I understood it, we both are eligible for CAN+ program visitor visas. My question is can I apply for my wife's visa at the same time as mine? If yes, what documents should I provide for her? She is a housewife.

Second, for me what documents do I need to submit along with the application? Please be specific with regard to the document list. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Both you and your spouse can apply at the same time, through the [visa application centre](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/contact-ircc/offices/find-visa-application-centre.html) in your locale.

> [**Is there a different application form for CAN+?**](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=875&top=16)
>
> No. Simply apply for a [visitor visa online or on paper](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp).
>
> For paper applications, check the [document checklist](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp) for full details of what you need to submit with your application.
>
> Please note:
>
> - Visa application centres are not involved in the visa decision-making process and can’t provide advice to applicants.
> - All decisions on applications are made by visa officers at Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada visa offices.
> - Applications that meet the criteria will also be processed faster.
>
> **[How do I know that my application can be processed under CAN+? What supporting documents should I submit?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=877&top=16)**
>
> [Visa application centres](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/contact-ircc/offices/find-visa-application-centre.html) will screen all applications for CAN+ eligibility. Applications that show that the applicant travelled to Canada in the last 10 years or holds a valid U.S. non-immigrant visa will be sent to the visa office for expedited processing.
>
> Check the [document checklist](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp) for full details of what you need to submit with your application.